# How to default some useState values and test the useState firing when there is a condition (state array should be equal to some value) on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

Actual code :

```
const [success, setSuccess] = React.useState(false);
const [ingredients, setIngredients] = React.useState([]);
const [ingredient, setIngredient] = React.useState("");

<input data-test="app-input" type="text" value={ingredient} onChange={(event) => 
setIngredient(event.target.value)} />

<button data-test="app-button"
      onClick={() => {
        if (ingredient) {
          if (ingredients.length === 2) {
            setSuccess(true);
          }
          setIngredients([...ingredients, ingredient]);
        }
      }}>Add<button>
```

Test code below :

Here only the on change input value is called mockSetSuccess

```
test("success state updated when click of the button", () => {
const mockSetSuccess = jest.fn();
React.useState = jest.fn(() => [false, mockSetSuccess]);
const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
const input = wrapper.find("[data-test='app-input']");
const button = wrapper.find("[data-test='app-button']");
input.simulate("change", { target: { value: "hello" } });
button.simulate("click", {});
expect(mockSetSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```

Can any body help to check the success state and the ingredients array state value

Comment: How did you use `success` and `ingredients` states?

Comment: Does this work: `expect(wrapper.state().success).toEqual(true)`?